# xamarin.android: tls support is not available (suddenly)

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin.forms

I was building apps with xamarin.forms before for a while, and of today: the first time my app connects to our API the app halts on no specific line stating:

```
 tls support is not available
```

I have changed nothing on my app, especially not in regard to the tls support.

[image]
Is anyone else having this issue?

This is the whole error message:

[image]

I have also noticed that the system generats a new file called_ mono_crash-json

its a long file like this:

```
{
  "protocol_version" : "0.0.6",
  "configuration" : {
    "version" : "(6.12.0.158) (2020-02/5ce143a1a88)",
    "tlc" : "normal",
    "sigsgev" : "altstack",
    "notifications" : "kqueue",
    "architecture" : "amd64",
    "disabled_features" : "none",
    "smallconfig" : "disabled",
    "bigarrays" : "disabled",
    "softdebug" : "enabled",
    "interpreter" : "enabled",
    "llvm_support" : "0",
    "suspend" : "hybrid"
  },
  "memory" : {
    "Resident Size" : "19333120",
    "Virtual Size" : "9451528192",
    "minor_gc_time" : "0",
    "major_gc_time" : "0",
    "minor_gc_count" : "0",
    "major_gc_count" : "0",
    "major_gc_time_concurrent" : "0"
 },
```

Comment: is this an exception?  If so, what is the specific exception thrown?

Comment: google `tls support is not available` - are any of those discussions relevant? When exactly does this message happen? During build? When running? On emulator or an actual device? Maybe search android forums - sounds like it is in android. OR maybe a symptom of some network problem, not your app? Reboot pc, reboot router?

Comment: @Jason see my edit

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I googled everything, there is hardly anything about it. It happens during the first rest call Im doing. If I leave those, the app renders fine.

Comment: I have also noticed that this seems to be more an issue of release builds...

Comment: *"It happens during the first rest call Im doing."* From what I read, there are two ways this can happen. 1) your network - something is blocking what is needed. 2) the website. Could there be an expired certificate? I suggest downloading [Postman Agent](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), and testing with that. May give more information about what is wrong.

Comment: No, both is fine. I was able to manually adjust the csProJ file and was able to get the build to work in debug. I need release tho, so I will continue to work on this and post a solution once I have one...

Comment: You can refer to this link(https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket
), the version you publish should meet its requirements.

Comment: Now its getting super weird: I was able to build a release but only with fast assembly deploiyment enabled. But than I cannot archieve the build... but I think I am close...

Comment: Whether there is any error message？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, enabling the linker and NOT setting it to "LINK NONE" solved this issue. For some reason, with a disabled linker, the linker must have removed libraries that were needed for the TLS support...