# xamarin.forms UNKNOWN TLS PROVIDER

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to load my app on android. It used to work before but suddenly stopped. At first, the app started, but upon the first REST call, it failed, stating there was an issue with the TLS provider.

Now the app doesnt even debug anymore and gives me this error:

[image]

Sometimes, when I change the linker from assemblies to none, the app still loads but crashes immeaditly upon the first rest call.
Sometimes, the below happens.

I did:
clean bin and obj
reisntalled mono
reinstalled vs
changed all possible build settings, linker and architectures

This error appears on vs 2019 mac and 2022 mac pre

anyone any idea what might be going on?

Sometimes I am able to debug and am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: have you searched "UNKNOWN TLS PROVIDER" and read any of the many, many similar questions?

Comment: can you show me a similar question please? ofc i googled

Comment: Surprisingly, that exact search doesn't give useful answers. Google `xamarin android problem tls site:stackoverflow.com`. But even that doesn't yield much useful information. The most recent one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065973/xamarin-android-tls-support-is-not-available-suddenly/70152894. What worked there looks like a work-around, which makes me wonder whether something changed recently in Xamarin. Ahh, you are building on Mac. For iOS or Android? This is debug build, right? When it worked before, was that before updating XCode and/or VS Mac? If simulator, Factory Reset?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve im at a point where i changed all settings and it worked again. then, just the next day, without doing any updates, I am back to square one. I really dont understand, but I believe it is an issue with the mono framework. however, reinstalling also didnt fix anything, but I noticed that crash logs are created inside the app called "mono_crash.123axxxxx" ...

Comment: Hmm. You got it to work once, then it failed again the next day. Maybe - 1) Factory Reset the device or emulator. 2) If using emulator, try actual device - or vice versa. 3) Can you get access to a pc for a day? See if VS 2019 or 2022 on pc works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have had the same issue in Visual Studio 2022.
Fixed it by altering the Android.csproj (Right click on the Android project File and select "Edit Project File").

In Visual Studio 2022 (Preview for me) it creates an attribute in the  for Release if you change the setting for "SSL/TLS implementation".

Removing the attribute `<AndroidTlsProvider>Default (Native TLS 1.2+)</AndroidTlsProvider>` from `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">` (Can be any platform/build) works for me

A rule of thumb: Always create a backup.

Comment: Did you know... this actually solved my issue. it randomly seems to reappeard but I could always fix it with this. There are two lines in the CSPROJ that include the keyword TSL in any way. I always remove both lines, dont even close the solution, just clean and rebuild and everyxthign works...